# How to create sharepoint 2013 statistical reports in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I wanna to create statistical reports for my sharepoint sites in SSRS. My sharepoint farm is 2013.
for wxample I try to create reports about how many user login in every site today, or last week, …
or which sites user1 browse today, or last week,… or how many times a special link had been clicked today, or last week,….
would you please guide me how to create statistical reports for sharepoint 2013 environment in SSRS?? 
or would you give me some links or articles about???

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that you don't have the framework for report creation in place, so I am going to give you information on how to get started which should hopefully also allow you to get an idea on how to create the reports when its all said and done.

1. [How to: Activate the Report Server Feature in SharePoint Central Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb677366%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)
2. [How to: Configure Report Server Integration in SharePoint Central Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb326213%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)
3. [Configuring Reporting Services for SharePoint 2010 Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326356%28v=sql.105%29.aspx/css)

Let me know if you need more help.

EDIT: Ok, so you have done the above and want to get to creating the actual reports, there are a few more things you need to do and here are a couple of resources that will be very useful to you. I don't want to recreate the wheel, so use this instead.

1. [How to Switch from SSRS Native Mode to SharePoint Integrated Mode](http://dereksan.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-switch-from-ssrs-native-mode-to.html)
2. [Create SSRS Report with SharePoint 2010 Integrated Mode](http://fendy-huang.blogspot.com/2011/02/create-ssrs-report-with-sharepoint-2010.html)

Good luck, let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks. but I wanna to know about how to create reports (Datasets, DataSources, ...) not configuring SSRS with sharepoint.

Comment: Ok, so you have done what I have linked, so I will post help on how to create the actual reports.